# Can't pop a customer view controller that is parent to a UIPageViewController off UINavigationController stack why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

Short version of question: When I pop a custom `UIViewController` that is parent to a `UIPageViewController` off a navigation stack, the app crashes  - why and what's the workaround? Longer description below:

I have a login screen that then pushes on top a customer `UIViewController` which itself is the parent of a `UIPageViewController` that presents a `UIPageView` in a section of the parent controller's view. Let's call this custom `UIViewController` B, which is parent to a `UIPageViewController` as I said. Here are the parent view controller's properties as declared in the .h file for view controller B:

```
@interface bjViewController : UIPageViewController  <UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource>
@property (strong, nonatomic)  UIPageViewController *pageController;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger index;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *screenNumber;
@property UIPageControl *childPageControl;
@end
```

And here is the troublesome code in viewDidLoad for view controller B:

```
UIViewController *initialViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:initialViewController];
[self.pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

[self addChildViewController:self.pageController];
[[self view] addSubview:[self.pageController view]];
```

If I comment this out, I can pop this view controller off the `UINavigationController` stack without a problem back to `UIViewController` A, but with these lines in, the app crashes when I navigate back to view controller A. However if I navigate back to A after popping something else on instead of B, there is no problem, so I'm fairly sure the crash has something to do with these lines I've pasted above.

What happens with the crash is that the app does re-present the view from A but then gives an `NSException` error without indicating where it's crashing (and I have NSLog in all my functions for that view controller - none of those functions are being executed).

Here's the error I get. Yes I do have a breakpoint for all exceptions but it just dumps to the @implementation line in the .m file for B, even as it's already presenting A. Here's the error it gives:

```
2015-04-21 10:08:14.958 [953:110883] -[UIView invalidatePageViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1655e940
2015-04-21 10:08:49.375 [953:110883] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView invalidatePageViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1655e940'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x26a0845f 0x3489ec8b 0x26a0d879 0x26a0b797 0x2693d008 0x2a4a08fb 0x2690effd 0x2692614d 0x348b8d5f 0x2a091e9d 0x2a4a0981 0x53e95 0x3489dda1 0x348a75f7 0x348a761b 0x2a225435 0x2a0921e9 0x2a4a0981 0x2a181cd7 0x34e45ae1 0x29f58e75 0x348b8d5f 0x2690effd 0x26928df3 0x348b8d5f 0x348b91a9 0x2691a139 0x269ccd1f 0x2691a3b1 0x2691a1c3 0x2df47201 0x29f8443d 0x7379d 0x34e2aaaf)
libc++abi.dylib: termina
```

Has anyone run into something like this? Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? I understand the basics of `NSException` and `NSInvalidArgumentException`, but I don't even know what's being called/incorrectly called.

Comment: Should you not have `[self.pageController didMoveToParentViewController:self]` after the `addSubview` call?

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel You are probably right about that. I just added it, but it does not impact the crashing.

Comment: The error would suggest that something in the hierarchy is expected to be a page view controller and it is a UIView instead hence why it cannot find the selector. You seem to be copying a controller from index 0 in self into self.pageController which seems odd to me as its duplicating the controller references, however not 100% sure what is happening in your code.